# ALLFITDIST function in MATLAB return 'rayleigh' as a best fit for normally distributed data

Tags: matlab, distribution, curve-fitting

The allfitdist function in MATLAB for normally distributed data return 'rayleigh' as best fit distribution! 
Here is the link of function: http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34943-fit-all-valid-parametric-probability-distributions-to-data

```
data = normrnd(5,3,1e4,1);
[D PD] = allfitdist(data,'PDF'); 
D(1)

              DistName: 'rayleigh'
               NLogL: 2.4515e+04 - 1.5959e+03i
                 BIC: 4.9038e+04 - 3.1919e+03i
                 AIC: 4.9031e+04 - 3.1919e+03i
                AICc: 4.9031e+04 - 3.1919e+03i
          ParamNames: {'B'}
    ParamDescription: {'scale'}
              Params: 4.1166
             Paramci: [2x1 double]
            ParamCov: 4.2366e-04
             Support: [1x1 struct]
```

So weird as it is an example included in file.
The second best fit is normal. The results are sorted by BIC, just wondering if I should change the sorting criteria or something is wrong with what I am doing.

Comment: I am getting `'normal'` as result. I've done three tests, and all three have ginven that. Maybe you got `'rayliegh'` just by chance. Data are random after all

Comment: Is it normal that you have complex values for example in BIC?

Comment: I've tried several times... So weird! what version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: I use 2010b. Did you try clearing all variables first?

Comment: yeah! i did that too. My friend also tried that and he gets Rayleigh result too in version 2014a.

Comment: I have tried it in MATLAB 2010b, and it works correctly. I don't know what part of the function dependencies in MATLAB has damaged during these versions. Anyway, Thanks @Luis Mendo for your helpful try :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following user3278640's answer, I tried out several versions of matlab. 2012b showed the normal distribution, while 2013b and 2014b showed the rayleigh as the best approximation.

While inspecting the values, it seems that the negative log-likelihood of the rayleigh in 2013b and 2014b is a complex number. I don't think that makes much sense, so I changed the code around line 209 from:

```
%If NLL is non-finite number, produce error to ignore distribution
if ~isfinite(NLL)
    error('non-finite NLL');
end
```

Into:

```
%If NLL is non-finite or complex number, produce error to ignore 
%distribution
if ~isfinite(NLL) || ~isreal(NLL)
    error('non-finite or non-real NLL');
end
```

That filters out the rayleigh distribution. Not really sure what changed between versions, but this might help.

Answer (score 0):

For saving time of the others, I have to highlight that this problem arises when you are using function ALLFITDIST in MATLAB 2014a. In version 2010b, everything is fine.

I won't accept this answer as a correct one, since it does not contain any information relating to the part of function that cause this dependency and problem.